# PayPal SDK sample created no logs

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have difficulties in getting PayPal SDK to create logs.  I ran the PayyPalAPISample of merchant SDK 2.7.109.  The file PayPalAPISampleLog.log is created but it is empty no matter what I did.  Is this normal?  How can I log requests passing to PayPal and their responses?

Comment: Which language SDK are you using?

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your response.  I tried digging into the source code of PayPal SDK and figured it out I need to define a value in app setting

<appSettings>
    <add key="PayPalLogger" value="PayPal.Log.DiagnosticsLogger, PayPal.Log.Log4netLogger" />
</appSettings>